# Select Printer to Print PDF file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, printing

I have to select a printer and print a PDF file.
here i used, **this code prints ONLY in the default printer**.. i tired for searching and didn't find a solution.

```
    Dim PrintPDF As New ProcessStartInfo
    PrintPDF.UseShellExecute = True
    PrintPDF.Verb = "print"
    PrintPDF.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    PrintPDF.FileName = "temp.pdf" 'fileName is a string parameter
    Process.Start(PrintPDF)
```

i had done another part to find the printers in dropdown list
this code to find printer

```
Dim pkInstalledPrinters As String
For Each pkInstalledPrinters In PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters
ComboBox1.Items.Add(pkInstalledPrinters)
Next pkInstalledPrinters     
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1
```

Is there any Suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I have added a web browser control in form.
add file file name of your pdf filename as follows:

WebBrowser1.naviagte(YourFileName)

Try
            WebBrowser1.Print()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

While Doing this your app show print dialog with  inbuilt option with which printer to you need to print.

Comment: ''MissSpell: WebBrowser1.navigate(YourFileName)